I am trying to webscrape the table data from the following published powerbi dashboard:
https://app.powerbigov.us/view?r=eyJrIjoiZDQxYTM0MDMtMGQ2Mi00ZTRkLThmNzQtNTYyYjBhNjhiMTQyIiwidCI6IjUwNzZjM2QxLTM4MDItNGI5Zi1iMzZhLWUwYTQxYmQ2NDJhNyJ9

from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://app.powerbigov.us/view?r=eyJrIjoiZDQxYTM0MDMtMGQ2Mi00ZTRkLThmNzQtNTYyYjBhNjhiMTQyIiwidCI6IjUwNzZjM2QxLTM4MDItNGI5Zi1iMzZhLWUwYTQxYmQ2NDJhNyJ9"

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(url)

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='grid']")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight;", table)

#WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda d: len(d.find_elements("xpath","//div[@role='row']")) > 21)
#tried the above code to wait for new rows to load
rows = driver.find_elements("xpath","//div[@role='row']") 
for row in rows: 
    try: 
        cells = row.find_elements("xpath",".//div[@role='gridcell' and not(@class='prefix-cell')]") 
        for cell in cells: 
            print(cell.text, end=" ") 
       
    except Exception as e: 
        print("Error:", e)
driver.quit()
#


I am using this code. There are 105 rows each in the 2 tables in the dashboard.
this code can only return 20 rows from both the tables.
Please suggest how to proceed. It will be really helpful if someone can suggest full code. I feel that the table is not getting scrolled and the whole page is getting scrolled.

Why don't you try to export it as CSV this way? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file#fileformat

Export CSV option is disabled in the dashboard and I need to automate the web scrape process
